# simultaneous connections to a mysql database

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I made a program that receives user input and stores it on a MySQL database. I want to implement this program on several computers so users can upload information to the same database simoultaneously. The database is very simple, it has just seven columns and the user will only enter four of them.

There would be around two-three hundred computers uploading information (not always at the same time but it can happen). How reliable is this? Is that even possible?

It's my first script ever so I appreciate if you could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having simultaneous connections from the same script depends on how you're processing the requests. The typical choices are by forking a new Python process (usually handled by a webserver), or by handling all the requests with a single process.

### If you're forking processes (new process each request):

A single MySQL connection should be perfectly fine (since the total number of active connections will be equal to the number of requests you're handling).

You typically shouldn't worry about multiple connections since a single MySQL connection (and the server), can handle loads much higher than that (completely dependent upon the hardware of course). In which case, as @GeorgeDaniel said, it's more important that you focus on controlling how many active processes you have and making sure they don't strain your computer.

### If you're running a single process:

Yet again, a single MySQL connection should be fast enough for all of those requests. If you want, you can look into grouping the inserts together, as well as multiple connections.

MySQL is fast and should be able to easily handle 200+ simultaneous connections that are writing/reading, regardless of how many active connections you have open. And yet again, the performance you get from MySQL is completely dependent upon your hardware.

Comment: I guess I won't have problems then. Thanks for the complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have up to that many number of mySQL connectins. It depends on a few variables. The maximum number of connections MySQL can support depends on the quality of the thread library on a given platform, the amount of RAM available, how much RAM is used for each connection, the workload from each connection, and the desired response time.

The number of connections permitted is controlled by the max_connections system variable. The default value is 151 to improve performance when MySQL is used with the Apache Web server.

The important part is to properly handle the connections and closing them appropriately. You do not want redundant connections occurring, as it can cause slow-down issues in the long run. Make sure when coding that you properly close connections.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html is a good start for info on this as well

Comment: I didn't realize I had to close the connections after each insert statement. Thank you!